# How to restrict the user to enter values other than the list in JCombobox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to restrict the user to enter values other than the list in JCombobox, that same time i want to perform autocompletion in JCombobox. So i am using SwingX library. some times it's restirct the user to enter values other than the list, but some times it's allowing.

Can anyone suggest me (or) give me any other solution is available?

Code is here:

```
Vector temp = new Vector();
        temp.add("");
        String sql = "select mat_uom from mat_type where mat_type = ?";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, matType.getSelectedItem().toString());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            temp.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(temp);
        matUom.setModel(model);
        AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(matUom);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yup the solution is already [available](http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/)

If you want to use automatic completion in your own project just download this [source code](http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/source/AutoCompletion.java). Then use the following snippet in your GUI code.

```
AutoCompletion.enable(yourComboBox);
```

Comment: i am tried your suggestion, but i got Null pointer exception, that same time first time, it allows me to enter other than the list values.

Comment: No it wont throw any exception.just run that Class seperately and see how it's working.And can you post your code.You might have initialized it wrong

Comment: Here i pasted my code, can you give me suggestion, if its required in my code. 
 Vector temp = new Vector();
rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                temp.add(rs.getString("f_nm"));
            }
            DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(temp);
            factory.setModel(model);
            //AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(factory);
            AutoCompletion.enable(factory);

Here i just created one project and pasted you suggested AutoCompletion code and attached the jar file to my project.